Clickhouse logic on Nth array item IF array is long enough
I would like to convert an array of string dates into two separate datetime columns.
The array will always have at least one string date, and sometimes it will have two strings dates. It will not have 3+
Extracting and parsing the first string is easy.
But the second one sometimes does not exist so I need logic to handle when it doesn't.
Unfortunately I am getting an error with my below attempt. The error suggests to me the parseDateTime function is being run regardless of if myArray[2] actually exists, which I had hoped the if clause would prevent. Note that both the dateTo and dateToAlternative query lines give the same error.
  with base as (
select ['2024-05-08 15:10:49'] as myArray
     ) 
select parseDateTime(myArray[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as dateFrom
     , case when length(myArray) > 1 then parseDateTime(myArray[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') else null end as dateTo
     , if(length(myArray) > 1, parseDateTime(myArray[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), null) as dateToAlternative
  from base


In the event of myArray only having one item I was expecting the if clause to return null.

Will you have at least one array with two dates? If so that's supposed to work (I changed your query to use CASE WHEN for convenience, yours is supposed to work as well):
with base as (
select ['2024-05-08 15:10:49'], ['2024-05-08 15:10:49','2024-05-08 15:10:49'] as myArray
     ) 

SELECT
    parseDateTime(myArray[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS dateFrom,
    CASE WHEN length(myArray) > 1 THEN parseDateTime(myArray[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') ELSE NULL END AS dateTo
FROM base


This worked for me:
  with base as (
select arrayMap(x -> parseDateTime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), ['2024-05-08 15:10:49']) as myDateArray
     ) 
select myDateArray[1] as dateFrom
     , case when myDateArray[2] = '1970-01-01 00:00:00' then null else myDateArray[2] end as dateTo
  from base

